# While upgrading from opensuse 13.1 to tumbleweed I am getting this error?

Tags: linux, opensuse

While upgrading to tumbleweed i am getting this error .

```
nothing provides kernel-pv-devel = 4.2.4-1 needed by kernel-syms-4.2.4-1.2.i586 . 
What to do ?
      Problem: nothing provides kernel-pv-devel = 4.2.4-1 needed by kernel-  syms-4.2.4-1.2.i586
    Solution 1: Following actions will be done:
    keep obsolete kernel-syms-3.11.10-29.1.i586
    keep obsolete kernel-desktop-devel-3.11.10-29.1.i686
    keep obsolete kernel-pae-devel-3.11.10-29.1.i686
    Solution 2: break kernel-syms-4.2.4-1.2.i586 by ignoring some of its
    dependencies
    Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): `
```

Comment: Welcome to *nix.SE! Please Don't provide where you can paste text.

Answer (score 0):

The version of kernel-pv-devel for the new kernel is not ready yet. This can occur on unstable systems like Arch, Debian Sid, or Tumbleweed where packages are not kept neatly in sync by releases.

You are being given a choice (option 1) to stay on your existing kernel or (option 2) to install the new kernel without some of its dependencies.

**Option 2 - Install the new kernel and ignore some dependencies**
You can try to install the new kernel if you don't need the development package kernel-pv-devel. You may need it for example if you don't get out-of-the-box graphics/sound/wireless drivers. However, watch carefully what happens next if you choose to do this, to avoid breakage.

**Option 1 - Keep existing (obsolete) kernel**
Or just stay on your current kernel. This is the least risky choice in terms of breakage but it may be insecure, since it is described as obsolete and is presumably no longer supported. Indeed, looking at LEAP's version of the 3.11 kernel, it has certainly been patched since then and you can assume that at least some of those patches relate to security.

But then a brand new kernel is not yet fully tested (that's your job!) and shouldn't be considered secure either.

My advice then is to stay on 3.11 (Option 1).

Ultimately, you are running an unstable system. If you prefer not to encounter this kind of scenario, you may wish to build up your confidence/expertise in LEAP first.

Comment: can you tell me how to upgrade to leap instead of tumbleweed ?

Comment: What version do you currently have? I think their existing stable distribution is considered Leap at the moment. However, going forward Leap will focus more on stability i.e. to compete with the likes of Debian(stable)/CentOS. The first actual release of Leap (42.1) is tomorrow (4 Nov). I would look at their release notes for upgrade instructions. If you are on openSUSE 13.2, you should be able to upgrade. However, if you are on Tumbleweed you will need to do a fresh install.

Comment: I have opensuse 13.1 installed .

Comment: This should help you to upgrade but back up your system first https://en.opensuse.org/Upgrade